# Creating Moose Objects to interact with an Oracle/mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, moose

I need guidance on creating Classes that will interact with Oracle/mysql.

The basic requirements would be to :

1. connect/disconnect to/from oracle/mysql database.
2. query tables and return data.
3. process data and create relevant html reports.

I am using Moose and would like to create Objects within the Moose framework. The projects I am involved with require these tasks to be performed regularly and I want to start making use of OOP to take advantage of the 'write code once' philosophy.

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a horribly generic question. You really need to be more specific about what information you lack that isn't covered in the Moose Docs (or that you couldn't find) and isn't covered by another module on CPAN (ie Fey or DBIx::Class, + TT2 or Mason would "solve" your basic requirements).

Comment: DBIx::Class++.  The report generation is (or, in my mind is) distinct from the ORM, and DBIx::Class will do what you need from that perspective.

Answer (score 1):

[DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/DBIx-Class-0.08205/lib/DBIx/Class.pm) is probably what you are looking for for managing the database connection/queries in an OOP style. It also works well with Moose.